# Online courses for Anomaly Detection

Tags: machine-learning, python, scikit-learn, unsupervised-learning, anomaly-detection

As the title say I have been looking for some online courses that would teach me about anomaly detection using Unsupervised Machine Learning.

I want to focus only on Scikit-Learn and not go deeper into TensorFlow or other options.

I have been looking at some Udemy courses but not really sure.

Decided to write here since the community here has a lot of knowledge and might lead me into the right path.
I am willing to pay for any course as long as it fulfills what I am looking for.

Comment: Scikit-learn has basically two options available (isolation forest and local outlier factor). They are quite simple and I think you can easily pick those up on your own without (paying for) an online course.

Comment: @oW_, you mean it has only these two options that you would recommand for outlier detection ?

Comment: Yes. You can take a look at the documentation [here](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/outlier_detection.html)

Comment: @oW_ what about dbscan, k-means , soetral clustering ?

Comment: if that is the case, you may want to try pyod with similar API like scikit learn, but 20+ algorithms. https://github.com/yzhao062/pyod